# xlsxwriter conditional formatting icon_set with mid value= 0 not showing proper arrow

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

The issue :
I want to apply conditional formatting icon_set using xlsx to a column but do not get the right arrows for the right values

**This is my desired output :**

[image: desired output]

**This is my current output:**

[image]

**This is my code:**

```
writer.sheets[sheet].conditional_format('J54:K200', {'type': 'icon_set',
                                                         'icon_style': '3_arrows',

                                                         'icons': [
                  {'criteria': '>=', 'type': 'number', 'value': 1},
                  {'criteria': '>=', 'type': 'number', 'value': 0},
                  {'criteria': '<', 'type': 'number', 'value': -1}

                                                         ]}
                                            )
```

**This is what I have looked at :**

Besides similar questions here, this is what I have done :

I looked at Excel for the formula and compared to my own work, to start from my output, and figure out the correct rule. 
The closest I got so far is that when I change my icons `'value'`to 2, 1, 0 respectively, I get the 1 to have the middle orange arrow:

[image: when the 1ns get the orange arrow]

This tells me that my equality must be correct, yet it doesn't produce the expected result. 
Thanks for any help provided!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you eliminate the `{'criteria': '>=', 'type': 'number', 'value': 0},` from your code it should work fine.  I have a reproducible example of this below with the expected output.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Creating a sample dataframe for example demonstration
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0, -1, 10, -2], 'col2': [-11, 0, -3, 1]})


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

writer.sheets['Sheet1'].conditional_format('A2:B5', {'type': 'icon_set',
                                                         'icon_style': '3_arrows',
                                                         'icons': [
                  {'criteria': '>=', 'type': 'number', 'value': 0.001},
                  {'criteria': '<=', 'type': 'number', 'value': -0.001}
                                                         ]}
                                            )


writer.save()
```

Expected test.xlsx:

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: This worked like a charm. For future users, as of the writing of this comment :  the documentation was misleading in this case :https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html?highlight=icon%20set saying that "The icons criteria parameter should be either >= or <. The default criteria is >=." I understood it as criteria parameter can't be <=.